# Setting the X/Y Offset for Ender 3 S1 Plus

Tags: 3d, firmware, ender

I recently did a Restore All Settings & updated the firmware on my Creality Ender 3 S1 Plus, and now when attempting to do the leveling the corners are not correctly aligned (for example, the front left is slightly off the bed). I know there is a way to fix this by changing some kind of setting, but I am not sure what it is or how to do it. Can anyone help me? Thanks.